# convergence of a sequence in $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

We provide $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the following distance function:

$d((x_n)_{n \geq 0},(y_n)_{n \geq 0})= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{2^{n+1}}$.

Let $\underline{a}^k = (a^k_n)_{n \geq 0} $ be a sequence of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\underline{a}^{\infty}= (a_n^\infty)_n \in [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$.

Show that $\underline{a}^k \to \underline{a}^\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n^k \to a_n^\infty$ when $k \to +\infty$.

I would be happy about some suggestions.

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$: $|a_n^k-a_n^\infty|\le2^{n+1}d(\underline a^k,\underline a^\infty)$.

Comment: For $\Leftarrow$: $$d(\underline a^k,\underline a^\infty)\le\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{|a^k_n-a^\infty_n|}{2^{n+1}}+2^{-N}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is easy:

If $a^k \rightarrow a$,
then for each $n$,
$$
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\lvert a_n^k - a_n \rvert}{2^{n+1}}
  \leq
  \mathrm{d}(a^k, a)
  \rightarrow 0.
\end{equation*}
$$
Therefore, $\lvert a_n^k - a_n \rvert \rightarrow 0$. That is, $a_n^k \rightarrow a_n$.

Now,
let's see the converse. Choose an $\varepsilon > 0$. And then, choose $n$ such that
$$
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{N=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{N+1}} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{equation*}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}(a^k,a)
&=
\frac{\lvert a_0^k - a_0\rvert}{2}
+
\frac{\lvert a_1^k - a_1\rvert}{2^2}
+
\dotsb
+
\frac{\lvert a_n^k - a_n\rvert}{2^{n+1}}
+
\sum_{\dotsb}^{\dotsb} \dotsb
\\
&\leq
\lvert a_1^k - a_1\rvert
+
\lvert a_2^k - a_2\rvert
+
\dotsb
+
\lvert a_n^k - a_n\rvert
+
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, just make $k$ big enough to make the first sums become less then $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.